# Wrong Error Message - Here Geocode API - InvalidCredentials

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I have a list of addresses which need to be translated to coordinates and Here Geocode API stopped in the middle of the list and returned "InvalidCredentials"/"PermissionError" which was wrong since my credential is valid.

The full Error message below:

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials"><Details>invalid credentials for </Details></ns2:Error>
```

Then I check my request, I found out that the problem is NOT about credentials but "#" in the address text.

The error message is wrong and it would be really helpful if Here can change their message specially to this case.

It is repeatable by having "#" in the address string:

Ex: https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=1920+River+Rd+Apt#57,+Tucson,+AZ&app_id=:your_app_id&app_code=:your_app_code&gen=9

It will return 200 and a success if you remove "#" in the request. Please also note that you may need to put your app id and app code to the url above.

Hope this post can help other people who have the same issue and Here API developers can see this and perhaps change its return message.

Comment: _“and Here API developers can see this and perhaps change its return message”_ - they don’t have to, because it is already correct. The _only_ parameter you are sending with the above URL is `searchtext` with the value `1920+River+Rd+Apt` - you did not send _anything else_ in the query string, because the query string ends with `#`. So you did not send any credentials, therefor the error saying “invalid credentials” _is correct_. (And as mentioned already in the answer, proper URL-encoding is the solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"#" needs to be encoded as %23. See [URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).